# How to have webpack completely ignore specific require statement

Tags: webpack, commonjs

I'm writing a library that exports a function like so:

```
function getFreshModule(absolutePath) {
  if (someCond) {
    delete require.cache[absolutePath]
  }
  return require(absolutePath)
}
```

Using webpack to compile this (babel) along with `libraryTarget: 'commonjs'` and `target: 'node'`.

For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to get webpack to ignore this.

I don't believe `externals` are the right thing for this, and I've also checked out the ContextReplacementPlugin, as well as fiddling with these options (snippet from docs).

```
{
  module: {
    // Disable handling of requires with a single expression
    exprContextRegExp: /$^/,
    exprContextCritical: false
  }
}
```

However, this does not seem to do what it says it does - as my require statement still gets replaced with the `__webpack_require_` function. I've also tried `module.noParse`, but that doesn't work either as then it isn't transformed via babel.

The rest of the library is normal, I just want it to specifically ignore this usage of `require`.

Comment: It's nuts, having the same problem.  Can't find any way to do it.

Comment: Even later to the party but while trying to solve this same problem I discovered `__non_webpack_require__`, a reference to the original require function at webpack runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I gave up trying to figure out how to do this.
So I pushed a new npm module 'external-require', which is simply:

`module.exports = (x) => { return require(x)}`

With 'externals' support in webpack config excluding this I can now do what I want.

One day I'll find out the proper way to do it.

Let me know if you want me to extend it support doing more require stuff e.g. deleting require.cache[]

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party, but I had a similar issue and fought for a while with Webpack with no avail. However, if you can make `require` part of a namespace, then you could do something like `app.require()` and Webpack will ignore it. Fortunately for me require was globally available on the `Window`.